# How to detect fullscreen?

Tags: linux, x11

Currently, I check if the window manager supports `_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN`. If it does then I use `XGetWindowProperty` to get array of atom's of `_NET_WM_STATE`. If it is the atom of `_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN` is found then i know it is fullscreen.

However on many windows, like the `Desktop` `WM_NAME` window, it doesn't have this atom. In fact doing doing `_NET_WM_STATE` fetch wit `XGetWindowProperty` fails, this i think is because the `_NET_WM_STATE` is removed when the window doesn't have focus? THe docs say its removed when window is unmapped.

I did test `Desktop`s width and height using `XGetWindowRect` and I compared it to the screen width and height by using macros of `WidthOfScreen` and `HeightOfScreen` and desktop does match full screen width and height. What's up with the atom missing? Any sure fire way to detect full screen?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to know? `_NET_WM_STATE` reflects the windows state agreed upon between the application and the WM. An application can decide to make the window span the entire desktop without having an agreement with the WM about that. If you want to check that the window spans the entire screen, you can check for just that condition. BTW a "fullscreen" window doesn't necessarily span the entire *screen* (as in X11 `Screen` object), it actually spans a monitor or a group of monitors.

Comment: Oh interesting stuff. Thanks @n.m. i was using this as a test to detect lockscreen/screensaver here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/567309/methods-to-detect-screensaver-and-or-locked

Comment: Why not ask dbus? `qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive` or something.

Comment: oh i didnt know of that option that is absolutely awesome! ill research that method, is using `dbus` a cross linux solution for lockscreen and screensaver? so ubuntu and all others?

Comment: should work in any modern desktop, but not necessarily with xscreensaver.

Comment: Thanks @n.m. so a solution to test for screensaver would be use dbus and also X11's XScreenSaver functions? http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XScreenSaverSuspend.3.html (and lock screen is just testing presence of screensaver huh?)

Comment: I actually mean the software known as xscreensaver, written by jwz. It doesn't use dbus. It may use the xscreensaver API in your link, I'm not sure.